# How can I retrieve video recordings sid from participant in Twilio?

Tags: php, laravel, twilio, recording

I'm currently working on Twilio Video recording, I have enabled recording to true

```
$client->video->rooms->create([
            'uniqueName' => $request->roomName,
            'type' => 'group',
            'recordParticipantsOnConnect' => true
        ]);
```

But then I want to retrieve the recordings (audio & video) based on participant sid. But it seems like there's no documentation on how to do that (Not including this one (https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/recordings-resource). Does anyone have any example or any reference I can look at?

Answer (score 0):

seems the link you posted is the way to do it. Have you tried?

```php
<?php

require_once '/path/to/vendor/autoload.php';

use Twilio\Rest\Client;

$sid    = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$token  = "your_auth_token";
$twilio = new Client($sid, $token);

$recording = $twilio->video->v1->recordings("RTXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
                               ->fetch();

print($recording->trackName);
```

Your `$sid` is somewhere here
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. But the question is, how do I get the recordings sid? I believe the sid "RTXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" is being retrieve from somewhere. But I do not have it anywhere unless I get it manually from my Twilio account.

Comment: @MuhammadAzraiBinSidratulMu  `$sid` is under your Twilio account

Comment: That's the ""ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"; I need the "RTXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" that's coming from participant / room.

Comment: @MuhammadAzraiBinSidratulMu so you may consider upvoting my answer?

Comment: Sorry but you're not answering my question

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I'm blind somehow. I found it in here https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/recordings-resource?code-sample=code-get-all-recordings-for-a-given-participant&code-language=PHP&code-sdk-version=6.x

```
$recordings = $twilio->video->v1->recordings
                            ->read(["groupingSid" => ["ParticipantSid"]],
                                   20


    );

foreach ($recordings as $record) {
    print($record->sid);

enter code here

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of recordings available in your twilio account through a program call, please refer the below code snippet

```
from twilio.rest import Client

    client = Client(api_key_sid, api_key_secret)
    recordings = client.video.recordings.list(status='completed', limit=20)
```

The output of `recordings` will be the list of recordings with the SID, you can then strip out unnecessary text and pass the SID values to the api endpoint
`https://video.twilio.com/v1/Recordings/{}/Media".format(sid)`.

The API endpoint will return a presigned S3 url which you can download through a GET request.